# Running spring boot with multiple main classes

Tags: spring-boot

Currently in our application we have multiple main classes and executing them individually using below commands separately.

java -Xmx1024M -cp /path/to/jar/MyApp.jar com.....MyAppMain1

java -Xmx1024M -cp /path/to/jar/MyApp.jar com.....MyAppMain2

java -Xmx1024M -cp /path/to/jar/MyApp.jar com.....MyAppMain3

Now trying to use spring boot. What do we do to achieve the same?

In pom.xml have

```
…….
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

……..
```

using spring boot and executing the command

java -Xmx1024M -cp /path/to/jar/MyApp.jar com.....MyAppMain1

getting error as 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project MyApp:The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java are missing or invalid

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean install` ? looks like error the packing, please try it and let us know.;

Comment: yes, tried it. Doing maven clean install didn't help. Looking close at the parent pom it is using exec-maven-plugin and is expecting the  start class   mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>. I am not sure how to pass this start class for different programs we have.

Answer (score 14):

Spring Boot gives several ways:

- specify main class as system property:

```
java -cp app.jar -Dloader.main=com.company.MyAppMain1 org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

- configure main class in Maven `pom.xml` `<properties>` section:

```
<properties>
  <start-class>com.company.MyAppMain1</start-class>
</properties>
```

Note that this property will only be evaluated if you use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as `<parent>` in your `pom.xml`.

- configure main class for `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
      <configuration>    
        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: plugin configuration can be performed in Maven profile, so by activating different profiles, you'll run app with different main class.

Comment: Thanks, for response. does the properties have to be provided as below without hardcoding the main right                                                    <properties> 
 <start-class>${loader.main}</start-class> 
</properties>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Also, how to run this program in eclipse? main class is passed as vm argument. Not sure how to run the program in eclipse

Comment: `<properties>` approach will work only if you are inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent`. If you do inherit from Spring's parent, then just set value of `loader.main` as parameter. There are multiple references [how to run Maven on eclipse](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html). I suggest to follow the instructions, e.g.: select pom.xml > Run As > clean verify > Add parameter etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Following are the different way to run Spring Boot main class:**

***1. Single main class in the Spring Boot Application***

A. via `<properties>` section

```
<properties>
     <start-class>com.company.MyAppMain1</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

***Note:***

1. When we use `start-class` property in `properties` section of `pom.xml`, we don't need to pass explicit value to plugin `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

B. via Custom property `<custom-mainClass>`

```
<properties>
     <custom-mainClass>com.company.MyAppMain1</custom-mainClass>
</properties>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
         <configuration>    
            <mainClass>${custom-mainClass}</mainClass>
         </configuration>            
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

***Note:***

1. Custom property `custom-mainClass` can be hard coded inside the property file as mentioned above 1.B
2. Pass by maven property using build as mentioned below:

   `mvn -U clean install -Dcustom-mainClass=com.company.MyAppMain1`

C. via Hard coded value in plugin `spring-boot-maven-plugin` section

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
         <configuration>    
            <mainClass>com.company.MyAppMain1</mainClass>
         </configuration>            
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

***2. Multiple main class in the Spring Boot Application***

A. via `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`

*Step 1:*

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
         <configuration>                    
            <mainClass>
               org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
            </mainClass>
         </configuration>            
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

*Step 2: Use below command to start application*

```
java -Dloader.main=com.company.MyAppMain1 -jar myapp.jar
```

*OR*

```
java -cp myapp.jar -Dloader.main=com.company.MyAppMain1 org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

***Note:***

1. Use `-Dloader.main` as Java VM arguments to pass dynamic main-class during start of application as shown in `step 2`

B. via Custom property `<custom-mainClass>`

```
<properties>
     <custom-mainClass>com.company.MyAppMain1</custom-mainClass>
</properties>

<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
         <configuration>    
            <mainClass>${custom-mainClass}</mainClass>
         </configuration>            
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

***Note:***

1. Pass by maven property using build as mentioned below:

   `mvn -U clean install -Dcustom-mainClass=com.company.MyAppMain1`

This also a dynamic `main-class` but its good only during maven build. Not applicable during application startup as shown in `step 2` of section `2.A`

Comment: thank you. THIS IS GREAT. If i could give more updooties, I would.